# Does Poison Queue exists in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I've created **Azure Service Bus** and I'm listening for messages using Azure Function.

If I'll throw exception in Function during handling the message. Then the entire process  will be repeted 10 times before the message will be moved to Dead-Lettered queue.

But what about poison queue? Why I can't see that queue nowhere? I even created such queue with the following name convention `{main_name}-poison` assuming that maybe there is some pattern for that, but no.

So does it mean that there is no Poison queue in **Azure Service Bus**, and that concept belongs only to eg. **Azure Queue Storage**?

Comment: Isn't Dead Lettered the same thing as Poisioned? just a different name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dead-Lettered queue is just another word for Poison queue. So they are the same thing :)

> Azure Service Bus queues and topic subscriptions provide a secondary
> subqueue, called a dead-letter queue (DLQ). The dead-letter queue
> doesn't need to be explicitly created and can't be deleted or managed
> independent of the main entity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues